# Array iteration using for loop in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, iteration

Lets say we have array with 5 elements and I have to iterate this array using for loop as given below:

```
int A[5]{2,3,5,9,1};
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    cout<<i[A];
}
```

I am able to iterate using this(i[A]), please explain how it works?

Comment: In what language? (Add the tag.)

Comment: No, you are accessing out of bounds because `i<=5` should be  `i<5`

Comment: What happened when you ran that code?

Comment: It works in code, but I don't know how it is working?

Answer (score 1):

Your errors:

```
int A[5]{2,3,5,9,1};
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) // accessing i <= 5 (out of bound of array), do it i < 5
{
    cout<<i[A]; // print A[i] not i[A], that's incorrect, i ain't an array
}
```

If you're doing the same in C++, then you could use `std::vector<>` instead.

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> A{2, 3, 5, 9, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        std::cout << A[i] << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`std::vector<>` has a lot of usage in today's C++. No longer you need to stick with static size of arrays.

As an alternative, you could do the same thing (like C-style):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int A[]{2, 3, 5, 9, 1};
    size_t len = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        std::cout << A[i] << ' '; // you're trying to access elements of 'A' not of 'i'

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This program dynamically allocates the size of array and iterates over `A[i]` until `i` is reached the size of array defined.

Comment: I got your point, but I guess my question was not correct as I wanted to know how this i[A] works fine.

Comment: @RahulBalyan the variable `i` isn't an array.

Comment: yes, but if you try iterate using this particular statement, it is working fine, I am able to print all the elements of an array. Please try it by yourself and u will know.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be legal. Simplistically ptr[count] is *(ptr + count) and it appears you can swap them around. *(count + ptr). One needs to be a pointer, the other an integer. Never ever seen it used in 40 years.